# jQuery not working with RequireJS when in subfolder

Tags: requirejs

I have the following folder structure:

- index.html
- js/

  - libs/

    - require.js
    - jquery.js
  - main.js

In index.html I added the following line to the head section:

```
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
```

When I add a simple alert to main.js, it works. When I want to use jQuery, it's not working:

```
require(['libs/jquery'], function ($) {
    $('#test').html('123');
});
```

In the chrome web inspector, I see that jquery loaded succesfully, but the text doesn't appear in my div. When I move jquery out of `./js/libs` and just put it in `./js` (and ofcourse change the dependency to `['jquery']`), it works.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I just put jquery in `./js/libs` to keep things organized?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that the DOM is not ready when your main.js runs and hence `#test` isn't updated?  Try wrapping your test code in `$( function() { ... });`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I configure a path

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'libs/jquery'
    }
});
```

and change the require to:

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $('#test').html('123');
});
```

it appears to be working. If someone could explain me why.

Comment: when jQuery calls `define` (the way AMD modules are defined/offered to any AMD loader) it gives itself the module-name `jquery`. Now if you call `require(['lib/jquery'], ...)` it will find `jquery.js` in `lib`, load the file and figure that there it is not named `lib/jquery` but only `jquery`. Therefore not the module you are looking for. At leasts that is how I understood this problem.

Comment: Its works even if you do not have the $ reference in the function call back because the jQuery refernce is in global scope. In order to avoid that you need to define jQuery as a module and resolve the name conflict and return it as an object. Something like define(["jQuery"], function(){ return jQuery.noConflict(true); });

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide basePath in order it to work correctly.
In your case it's just **js**. You can do it in the beginning on main.js file.

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js'
});
```

after that this code will work, because it will concatenate baseUrl with your relative url.

```
require(['libs/jquery'], function ($) {
    $('#test').html('123');
});
```